# Open Office - download Java code samples with Tortoise SVN

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, openoffice.org

I'm trying to download some code samples from the Openoffice wiki site (https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples) but so far without success. I use the Tortoise SVN client and to download the code I have created a new folder on my Windows PC. I then right click on this folder and choose "SVN Checkout", add the URL of repository (in this case "https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples") and click. However I get the error "Server sent unexpected return value (503 Service Unavailable) in response to". 
Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong here? I know very little about Tortoise SVN and have never used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the url you are using is not the correct one as Keugyeol already pointed out, but still the "official" link will not work because the host name is no longer active.

However, [the following](https://github.com/vmiklos/lo-sdk-examples) is supposed to be a mirror of that site and you should be able to get your examples downloaded from there. (https://github.com/vmiklos/lo-sdk-examples)

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct URL. If you go into that URL, you'll find the sample command under the section **Checkout the sourcecode** i.e. the correct URL seems in the form of `svn://svn.services.openoffice.org/ooo/contrib/sdk/examples/java`

Comment: I just tried that URL but get Unknown hostname 'svn.services.openoffice.org'